# EXCEL: Find minimum between the sums of multiple values from several columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Excel 2019 for Mac.

I have **10 columns containing prices** from different suppliers.
I also have **398 rows of products, each with a corresponding price** in each of the 30 columns.
Each supplier also has a **unique delivery cost at the the top of the column**. This is constant per product per supplier.

I would like to be able to calculate the minimum value for each row and match the supplier name, but this has to also take into account the delivery cost.
Currently, this is being done without the delivery cost and it works just fine.

If we assume that:

- supplier names are in C2:L2;
- prices are in C3:L400;
- product names are in A3:A400
- cheapest suppliers are in B3:B400.

The current formula in CELL B3 to match the name of the cheapest supplier is:
**= INDEX($C$2:$L$2,1,MATCH(MIN(C3:L3),C2:L2,0)**

Now, I have added delivery costs in C1:L1 and would like to take them into account in the MIN part of the formula.

For example, currently, if I have prices $10 and $11 in C3 and D3 respectively, the cheapest supplier is in column C.
However, if I also have delivery costs $3 and $1 in C1 and D1 respectively, the cheapest supplier is now in column D.

|  | *delivery costs:* | 3 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Products** | **Cheapest supplier** | **supp1** | **supp2** |
| Product1 | = ?? | 10 | 11 |
| Product2 | = ?? | 1 | 2 |

I know I can just alter the MIN part of the formula as MIN(C3+C$1,D3+D$1,.....L3+L$1), but this is very inefficient, considering that I have another 20 columns of prices that I have to add to the matrix.
It would be nice if there is a formula that can easily be expanded/contracted.

Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the dollar sign to a cell reference address? Just try `C3+C$1` instead `C3+C1`

Comment: @dizaj, Excel version?, please share sample data using [Table Markdown] (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format.

Comment: @JohnSUN sorry, I forgot to add it here, edited it now. I do, in fact, know the meaning, but this does not solve my problem. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @DavidLeal Excel 2019 for Mac, added it now at the top. Added the table as well, had no idea I could do that, I apologize!

Comment: The `=INDEX($C$2:$L$2;1;MATCH(SUMPRODUCT(MINIFS(C3:L3+$C$1:$L$1;C3:L3;"<>";$C$1:$L$1;"<>"));C3:L3+$C$1:$L$1;0))` formula worked for me. Perhaps there is a simpler way to write this (for example, if you are sure that all cells up to column L contain some value - I tried to handle possible empty cells)

Comment: @JohnSUN I cannot get it to work for some reason. Excel just does not recognize anything in the lookup_array part of the MATCH. Every array is just greyed out and I have run out of possible things to try to fix it. Any clues?

Comment: Well, if you are sure that all cells from column C to column L contain values, then use a simpler version of the formula - `{=INDEX($C$2:$L$2;1;MATCH(MIN(C3:L3+$C$1:$L$1);C3:L3+$C$1:$L$1;0))}` *(use **CONTROL+SHIFT+RETURN** to enter a formula as an array formula)* Keep in mind that empty cells will add a non-existent value of 0 and the formula will not give the correct result!